# Using ng-repeat with data from two JSON files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I am building some sort of online course library and I am simulating DB data as `JSON` files for now. What I am attempting to do is show in an `ng-repeat` the courses the user has acquired. I have two `JSON` files, one for the users and another for the courses and I would like to know how can I cross-reference both files to show the data that I want.

I have data form two `JSON` files stored in a two variables as stated below:

```
//load user data
$http.get("users.json")
.then(function mySuccess(response){
    $scope.appUsers = response.data;
}, function myError(response){
    console.log("Error loading user data!");
});

//load course data
$http.get("courses.json")
.then(function mySuccess(response){
    $scope.appCourses = response.data;
}, function myError(response){
    console.log("Error loading course data!");
});
```

The data from the two JSON files (courses.json and users.json) looks something like this:

**users.json**

```
[{
    "username": "user1",
    "password": "123456",
    "name": "Joe",
    "courses": [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 3}, {"id": 4}, {"id": 5}, {"id": 6}, {"id": 7}, {"id": 8}]
}, {
    "username": "user2",
    "password": "654321",
    "name": "Jane",
    "courses": [{"id": 2}, {"id": 4}, {"id": 5}, {"id": 7}]
}]
```

**courses.json**

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Web Design",
    "image": "images/portfolio/p1.jpg",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam et faucibus metus, ac efficitur felis.",
    "price": "35€"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Photoshop Level 1",
    "image": "images/portfolio/p2.jpg",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam et faucibus metus, ac efficitur felis.",
    "price": "35€"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Game Design",
    "image": "images/portfolio/p3.jpg",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam et faucibus metus, ac efficitur felis.",
    "price": "35€"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Photography Level 1",
    "image": "images/portfolio/p4.jpg",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam et faucibus metus, ac efficitur felis.",
    "price": "35€"
}, {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Web Design Masters",
    "image": "images/portfolio/p5.jpg",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam et faucibus metus, ac efficitur felis.",
    "price": "35€"
}, {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Photoshop Level 2",
    "image": "images/portfolio/p6.jpg",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam et faucibus metus, ac efficitur felis.",
    "price": "35€"
}, {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Game Design Masters",
    "image": "images/portfolio/p7.jpg",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam et faucibus metus, ac efficitur felis.",
    "price": "35€"
}, {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Photography Level 2",
    "image": "images/portfolio/p1.jpg",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam et faucibus metus, ac efficitur felis.",
    "price": "35€"
}]
```

I have this `ng-repeat` tag with an `ng-if` to simulate "user1" has logged in:

```
<div ng-repeat="course in appCourses" ng-if="appUsers[0].username == 'user1'">...</div>
```

Now I am missing what I am supposed to do to show only the courses that user1 has.

Thank you.

Comment: is `users.json` something you generate / can change?

Comment: Yes, I wrote it myself, its all dummy data for now.

Comment: Instead of `[{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}...]`, just use an array of ids: `[1, 2...]`, that'll make it a heck of a lot easier, already.

Answer (score 0):

Before executing the ng-repeate, you could loop through your user's and course's (in the javascript) and add the related course's as a array to each user.

Then you could simply do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="course in user.courses">...</div>
```

or

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users"><div ng-repeat="course in user.courses">...</div></div>
```

What exactly do you want to display anyway?

Comment: courses.json is like a generic DB table that contains all the available courses, while the users.json contains information about the users. What I want is to diplay the courses user1 has, in this case.

Comment: So I would recommend to add the courses as an array to each user. I think kylem42's approach is good. Just be sure to initialize "$scope.appUsers" and validate it before accessing one of its items.

Comment: I know I am just still learning this but I wasn't expecting to not understand most of your (all) tips. What do you mean by initializing and validating? Isn't the code to asign data to $scope.appUsers already doing that?

Comment: I mean that you should secure that "$scope.appUsers" actually exits and that the array actually has items before you access them. If you access $scope.appUsers[0] you should check if there axtually is at least one item in the array, because the error said it would be undefined which means you want to access something that doesn't exist. Something like if($scope.appUsers != null && $scope.appUsers.length > 0){...}

Comment: Oh ok, i get it now. That actually makes sense. Will give it a try later today. Appreciate it.

Comment: I actually didn't. And unfortunatelly I don't have time to keep trying this, at least not right now. I went with changing the JSON files. Mixed it all in one file with all the data. Not what I was aiming for but will have to do for now.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to change the users.json file (or API) so it includes the course data you need, instead of just the ID.

If that's not possible, try something like this:

```
// do some check to see which user is signed in, in this case it's user1
$scope.currentUser = $scope.appUsers[0];

var i = 0;

angular.forEach($scope.currentUser.courses, function(courseId) {
  var selectedCourse = $scope.appCourses.filter(function(course) {
    return courseId === course.id;
  })[0];

  angular.merge($scope.currentUser.courses[i], selectedCourse); // adds all necessary course data to that user's courses array

  i++;
});
```

Then all you need to do in your template would be:

```
<div ng-repeat='course in currentUser.courses'>
  <!-- all course info here -->
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your approach since it seems pretty complete for what I needed and I could actualy learn something from this but I am getting an error right at the `$scope.currentUser = $scope.appUsers[0];` part: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: It seems that it cannot assign the object to the variable, but I can actually do it in Chrome console...